# Non-inverting amplifier giving nothing as output

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a UA741CP and I am connecting Pins 4 and 7 to + and - 12 V. When I provide a signal only the voltage follower works fine and I can see the output on Pin 6 matching my input signal. However the inverting and non-inverting give no output on Pin 6.

What could be going wrong ?

Comment: Post a schematic...

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: What does "no output" mean? There must surely be some DC level on the output even if you can't see the AC signal you mention in a comment. Knowing that, and the schematic, will probably provide your answer.

Comment: Also how much gain are you trying to get with your inverting and non-inverting configurations?  Is there any DC offset in your input? What's the frequency of your input signal?  A schematic would help greatly.

Comment: This isn't the answer to this particular problem, but: please don't use the 741. It's very outdated.

Comment: I am connecting the ground of my Function generator to the ground of my circuit. The ground of my circuit is the mid point of my dual power supply of 12 V each connected in series.

Comment: Frequencies I have tried are 100 to 2 kHz

Comment: I am trying to get a gain of 10 with 2 V pp signal. Will provide a circuit diagram tomorrow

Comment: Hearth which IC should I use ?

Comment: The ground for my oscilloscope is also the ground of my circuit. Maybe something going wrong with the ground of my FG and OSC, which I have kept the same as the ground of my circuit

Comment: LM358 is also very old but MUCH easier to use than a 741. Also low cost. Input common mode range includes ground. || 2V x 10 = 20V = beyond suppies. || Please use the inbuilt schematic editor - amazingly intuitive and easy to use. Opens in question box using Ctrl-M

Comment: Adding a cct diagram MAY save this question being closed. It can be reopened on requset if adequately updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pins 4&7 are reversed in your description.  (Oh-oh)

p7=+, p4=-

When using the inverting mode for gain, choose high R values (>10kohm) to stay away from output active current limit.  Match thevenin Rvalues for nulling input bias current that creates some input Offset, if significant.

The logical way to debug is if both inputs are at the same voltage , the output should be linear and near correct value. If Not the R values may be too small.

=========

When Vin+(p3) > Vin-(p2) , Vout (p6) saturates high.

Since you have a gain of 4.7+1 =5.7 your Vin+ max range is 0 to <1.5 as 1.5 x 5.7 = 8.5V in saturation near 9V.

Comment: Thanks for replying Tony. I think that is done right. Pin 4 is - 12V and Pin 7 is +12v. I did not specify the order in my question for which I am sorry. Something else is wrong maybe in the chip, dont know

Comment: I have tried signals from 2 - 3 V PP and 100 to 1 Khz. But cant get it right

Comment: Check V on p2,p3,p6

Comment: I am using Rf = 47kohms, Ri = 10 kohms. I changed voltage to Pins 7 and 4 to +9 V and -9V respectively. Voltages on Pin 2 - 1.55 V, Pin 3 - 6.17V and Pin 6 - 9.01 V.

Comment: I have observed when I remove Ri circuit works like a perfect voltage follower, inspite of Rf still present in the circuit.

Comment: I am using a non-inverting configuration

Comment: So when Ri goes to ground it causes Pin 6 to goto basically nothing

Comment: There is some issue in my chip. Pin 3 should not be at 6 Volts. I am not supplying 6 Volts to PIN 3. But I think your analysis is correct in the sense that Pin 3 is driving Pin 6 to saturation. Will try with another chip

Comment: It looks like you broke it.

Comment:  I bought it on Amazon. But I see another guy's review on the item from that seller on the exact same issue. So I will try some other seller and chip brand. This one was from ST - at least the logo said that

Comment: Did it ever run with reverse supply?  What is the Vin+ current? I presume you used a series R as Vin+ must be driven lower than gain permits yet you said it measured >6V. IC’s are all 100% tested.. even clone designs.

Comment: Reconfigured the circuit and used R series with P3 input. Pin3 at 1.61 V, Pin2 at 2.41V and Pin 6 still at 8.37 Volts. Rf = 100 kohms , connecting Pin6 to Pin 2.  Ri = 47kohms connecting Rf to ground.

Comment: using 9 V battery to power the opamp. 9V at Pin 7 and ground at Pin 4. Still 8.54 Volts at Pin 6

Comment: So now the expected gain is only around 2. Opamp output should not saturate... right ?

Comment: current in Pin 3 is 1.4 amps, Pin 2 is 3.9 amps, Pin 6 13.7 amps

Comment: Too many concerns in your comments, means you need to show schematic and wiring in future with measurements, but its broken.  If it doesn’t work as a comparator, with +>- or  +<-  then it’s broken, as long as inputs are within Vcm range and output saturates to either rail according to Vdiff input. Try again with new part.

Answer (score 0):

My function generator was giving a 6V DC Bias because of which the problems. I used another FG and the circuit works expected. There wasnt any problem in the chip. Thanks for the support Tony.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for coming back with an answer to your question. In order to mark the topic as solved, please consider "[accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)" an answer - yours or another one - according to the guidelines in that link. Then your question is shown as having an accepted answer in various lists, and we don't get nagged for it being a question with an unaccepted answer. Thanks.